# Rstudio to Presto connectivity

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to connect Rstudio to Presto connectivity and am
receiving the error below. Please help me with support on this issue.

```
 Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
      Empty reply from server
```

I am using the below steps, submitting the code to an Rstudio application:

```
library(RPresto)
library(dbConnect)

conn <- dbConnect(Presto(), catalog = 'ares', schema = 'default',
user = 'onur', host = 'localhost', port = 443,
session.timezone='US/Eastern')
dbListTables(conn, '%_iris')
dbDisconnect(conn)
```